# Is it safe to carry bear spray on a GA plane?

Tags: safety, general-aviation

I'm aware that bear sprays are normally banned from commercial flights, including in checked bags. As I'm not sure of the reason behind that, I'm in turn unsure of whether it's wise to have some with me in my Cessna as I take it to go backpack.

Are there risks to having bear spray with me, flying up to 12,500 ft?

Additionally, why is bear spray banned from commercial flights (I mean in checked bags, it's pretty obvious why they don't want that in the cabin)? Is it the difference of pressure? Surely these things are made to withstand pressures up to 13 or 14k feet, as they could very well be taken that high when simply hiking?

Comment: When you're hiking, you can toss the can of bear spray safely away from you if it starts leaking.  Try doing that in an enclosed airplane cabin.

Comment: Interesting your perspective.  The reason it's outlawed in commercial flights is how useful it would be to terrorists trying to take over the airplane.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Also, the chance of encountering any bears at 10,000+ ft. is pretty much nil, so there aren't too many legitimate reasons to have it accessible during the flight...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I meant why is it forbidden to have in checked bags, where it's not accessible during the flight.

Comment: Imagine being an airline manager, responsible for passenger safety in a multi-million dollar (a 777 is 306 million) aircraft -- and their luggage.  A passenger puts bear spray in their luggage, maybe leaky or a broken anti-discharge safety (dropped on rocks, sabotaged as a prank, whatever) and it discharges... into the middle of an aircraft hold full of luggage.  It all has to be cleaned, passengers placated and compensated, and a 777 costs around $7,380 per hour to operate.  You want to delay flights, handle that cleaning job, all the fallout?  Would YOU say "sure, no problem, pack it"?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The main danger in a light aircraft is that the spray accidentally discharges in the cabin. That could temporarily blind and incapacitate the pilot, which would obviously be extremely dangerous.

According to [an article](http://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=wildlifenews.view_article&articles_id=861) from the Alaska Department of Fish and Game, GA operators typically take special precautions when transporting bear spray:

> You can take bear spray, but you must tell the carrier and the pilot
> must know. It requires special handling. Carl Ramseth is with Alaska
> Seaplanes, a Southeast Alaska regional service, which has planes on
> both floats and wheels. Bear spray is defined as a hazardous material,
> he said.
>
> “You can fly with it, but it needs to be declared,” he said. “We ask
> passengers as they check in – people on scheduled flights as well as
> people going to remote locations. People don’t realize it could be a
> problem, so we always ask. There is paperwork filled out. We transport
> it in a sealed can, stored in a part of the aircraft that is not in
> the main cabin, so there is no risk of it going off in the cabin. Or
> it goes in the float compartment of a float plane.”
>
> Some carriers use a length of heavy duty black PVC sewer pipe, four
> inches in diameter and threaded with caps at both ends. Several cans
> can be stacked and sealed in the tube for transport.

[Another article](http://www.adfg.alaska.gov/index.cfm?adfg=wildlifenews.view_article&articles_id=238) on the same site says that some operators don't want to carry it at all:

> “Bear spray is a big one, it’s dangerous,” said Stewart of Skagway
> Air. “We can do it, but we really prefer not to. Typically speaking,
> most carriers won’t allow it. You don’t want that going off in an
> aircraft.”
>
> “We really try to have them leave it behind,” said Vanessa Thompson,
> with 40-mile Air.

Even if you don't have a floatplane, as long as you have some duct tape it's still possible to carry the spray outside the cabin:

[image: Bear spray taped to aircraft strut]

[ilya_ktsn](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bear_spray_taped_to_strut.jpg), [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0), via Wikimedia Commons

It might look odd, but it's allowed by the FAA per [JO 8400.34 - *Fixed-Wing External Loads in Alaska*](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1033669):

> Items in this group are small, lightweight, and temporarily attached
> with bungee cords, straps, ropes, etc. Below is a list of items that
> are examples that may  be carried under a Standard Airworthiness
> Certificate. For the purpose of this order, these
> temporarily-attached items are not considered design changes or
> alterations.
>
> [...]
>
> Cans of animal repellent, such as bear spray or pepper spray.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a way better answer to the main question than mine, since it brings out the real world comments about the bear spray. All in all, if pros don't want to fly with that stuff in the cabin, well...

Comment: Remember that even pepper spray for use on _humans_ can easily incapacitate a human (that being, after all, its primary intended purpose), and bear spray is _much_ more potent than human spray.

Comment: I just did this a few weeks ago with another Southeast Alaska regional service. They put the bear spray in a container in the float (the kerosene went in the float too). This is how I've always seen it done here.

Comment: ah, duct tape. The universal cure where WD40 is inappropriate :)

Comment: Now let's go crop-dust some bears!

Comment: @jwenting Seems like it should be speed tape in aviation, though. - haha

Answer (score 11):

Second things first (just because I can):

Bear sprays such as [this Wikipedia example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bear_spray) are banned as carry on luggage on airliners for two reasons:

1. They are aerosols, which generally are banned
2. They contain capsaisine, meaning they essentially are a pepper spray, and could be used as a weapon.

[TSA has ruled](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/pepper-spray) that:

> One 4 fl. oz. (118 ml) container of mace or pepper spray is permitted in checked baggage provided it is equipped with a safety mechanism to prevent accidental discharge. Self-defense sprays containing more than 2 percent by mass of tear gas (CS or CN) are prohibited in checked baggage.

I am unaware of any rule or regulation banning bear sprays on general aviation aircraft, but unless the container was equipped with a safety device described in TSA rule, I would not take one on a plane.
Not that I would be worried about the container bursting, but simply because any kind of accidental discharge could very well prove to be fatal.

If you ever have had the chance to try how it feels to be maced, you know you immediately end up in IFR without the possibility to read the gauges. The experience is blinding and very, very painful.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128848/discussion-on-answer-by-jpe61-is-it-safe-to-carry-bear-spray-on-a-ga-plane).